# Emacs cond, possible to have things happen between clauses?

Tags: emacs, conditional-statements, elisp

I programmed some months ago some code with a lot of `if` statements. If `region-active-p`, if `beginning-of-line`, those kind of things.

Having learned about the `cond` lisp, I was wondering if I could improve my code a lot.

The problem is that this `cond` is only doing things when "true" as far as I see it, while I actually need the move `back-to-indentation` in between these checks.

In order to properly skip the last clause, I even have to set variable values.

```
(defun uncomment-mode-specific ()  
  "Uncomment region OR uncomment beginning of line comment OR uncomment end"
  (interactive)
  (let ((scvar 0) (scskipvar 0))
    (save-excursion
      (if (region-active-p)
         (progn (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
         (setq scskipvar 1))
        (back-to-indentation))   ; this is that "else" part that doesn't fit in cond

      (while (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) comment-start) 
       (delete-char 1) 
       (setq scskipvar 1))
      (indent-for-tab-command)

      (when (= scskipvar 0)
         (search-forward comment-start nil t)
         (backward-char 1)
         (kill-line))
    )))
)
```

So basically my question is, I would kind of like to have some consequences of not giving "true" to a clause, before the check of another clause. Is this possible? If not, what would be the best thing to do?

EDIT: Since we are using this as the example case for a solution, I wrote it down so it is easier to understand.

If region is active, remove comments from region. If not, move point to intendation.

For as long as the following character is a comment character, delete it. Afterwards, indent this line.

If it didn't do any of the above, search forward for a comment character, and kill that line.

Comment: BTW `uncomment-or-comment-region` is already mode specific. (as is `uncomment-region`)

Comment: I know, but these don't work yet when no region is selected. As you can see this combines when a region is selected, and when it is not. (oh and it is not "uncomment-or-comment" its more like "uncomment-region-or-something-else")

Comment: I've not really studied what you're trying to do here, all I've provided in the answer is an exposition of what `cond` does. Which given your current logic tree, isn't what you want.

Comment: @wvxvw yup `cond` looks like a switch, but the `break` statements are implicit for each clause. Making far less flexible.

Comment: What I'd like is a `cond`, which could evaluate some code (e.g. move point) in between clauses. That would clean this code up tremendously. So it should still exit upon getting a "true". I believe this is different than what you meant @wvxvw?

Comment: The silly thing here is that I have to use these variables, while a cond would do exactly this if only I could move the point between clauses for some checks.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you want to comment the current region OR the just the current line if no region is marked. I think there's a few ways you can do this more simply.

Comment: There is one more OR involved; I would like it to remove all the comment characters at the beginning of the line (if no region). If it did this it can skip the next part. The next part is to remove all the comment characters at the end of the line.

Comment: why not do an `(or )` ? Build a list of actions that finally return a true or false, `or` will keep going until it evaluates true, which doesn't mean you can't execute the previous clauses, they just need to supply a false when they're done.

Comment: Haha the irony. I didn't know about that one. I will check it out and report back.

Comment: Expanded on it above, low-level logic programming, and possibly causes a hitch for another maintainer, including future you, when you've forgotten what you did. They're extremely clean and exist (and is exploited) in pretty much every programming language.

Comment: I'd like to add that you shouldn't think of `cond` as an 'inflexible switch', because each branch evaluates to a result. The idea is that you *return* something, rather than side-effecting.

Comment: You are saying that the above code is low-level logic programming and that this will confuse me later on, or that it is clean?

Comment: If you're going to refactor this functional-style, I'd suggest breaking it up into simple predicate functions, then 'and/or' them up in the cond clauses. You'll be able to follow the control flow better.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett that's right, I'm probably pussy footing around the fact that switch sucks.

Comment: Chris, thanks. I am quite amazed that this code does exactly what I want, but it is hideous.

Comment: @Dualinity I think it sounds like you could do some `(and)` `(or)` experiments and learn a lot about these simple operators. Try and avoid the side effects necessary to achieve what you want (ie. try and do this without passing the variable around.)

Comment: I read up on (or ) and I believe that still it is not possible to do things BETWEEN seperate checks for true (my `or` is the only one not syntax colored?).

Comment: @Dualinity play with `or` / `and` it's more valuable than reading about it.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that neither `or` nor `and` will be able to allow for moving point in between?

Comment: Btw Chris, I am very aware that I want each case in `cond` to return a `nil` or a `t`, except that I would like it to also move point before the next check.

Comment: @Dualinity why not? Each expression you evaluate in your `and` `or` lists can do anything you want before they return their boolean result. It's simply a case of `or` behaves a lot like `cond`, while `and` executes until it reaches false.

Comment: Ah I really just thought of one `or` to-do-it-all. I will try combinations.

Comment: Oh by the way, what about comment-end ?

Comment: Easily extendable, but I only use R, LaTeX and Emacs so far, which all only have comment starts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22112/discussion-between-dualinity-and-slomojo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun delete-on-this-line (regex)
  (replace-regexp regex "" nil (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))

(defun delete-leading-comment-chars ()
  (delete-on-this-line (eval `(rx bol (* space) (group (+ ,comment-start)))))) 

(defun delete-trailing-comment-chars ()
  (delete-on-this-line (eval `(rx (group (+ ,comment-end)) (* space) eol))))

(defun delete-trailing-comment ()
  (delete-on-this-line (eval `(rx (group (+ ,comment-start) (* anything) eol)))))

(defun uncomment-dwim ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (if (region-active-p) 
        (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (or (delete-leading-comment-chars) 
          (delete-trailing-comment-chars)
          (delete-trailing-comment)))))
```

---

**Edit:** A little explanation: 
It's a lot easier to do regex replacements than manage loops to do deletion, so that gets rid of the state. And the steps are all mutually exclusive, so you can just use `or` for each option.

The `rx` macro is a little DSL that compiles down to valid regexes, and it's also amenable to lispy syntax transforms, so I can dynamically build a regex using the comment chars for the current mode.

Comment: This only misses the part for which, if all those cases don't hold, it searches for the first comment at the end of the line, and kills that line.

Comment: Example: When the point is anywhere in the following string: "blabla ;;test" it should kill ";;test"

Comment: This might just be me, but it is quite complex and does not read that easily. It is compact code though.

Comment: Yeah, the calls to rx look nasty, what with all the quotes and evals. If you're only using it with a given mode, you can compile those regexes down to strings. But as it is, it should work for any mode with defined comment chars.

Comment: Curiosity, are you using something like this yourself? Oh and, minor request, could you remove the "replaced x occurances"?

Comment: I'd rather read `(rx bol (* space) (group (+ ,comment-start)))` than `"^[[:space:]]*\\(;+\\)"`, but that's just personal taste. ;)

Comment: Nah, I use evil-mode so I don't bother writing complex editing commands much anymore. Not sure if there's anything I can do about the message - it's internal to replace-regexp.

Comment: Aha, I was about to ask for that! Since I was not familiar with the first, this last part does make a lot more sense to me.

Comment: Wow, someone who uses evil. Did you start with vim or with emacs?

Comment: Chris, that second part `"^[[:space:]]*\\(;+\\)"` does not have the `comment-start` included? Is that still possible in that kind of notation?

Comment: I started with Emacs and got into writing brittle AI-style dwim-commands for everything, before I got fed up and learned to love the bomb.

Comment: @Dualinity: That string is just a straight regex, whereas `rx` is a lisp macro (as in, it works with valid lisp code). That's how I can access variables at runtime. I think you *can* embed lisp code in Emacs-Lisp regexes, but I don't want to know what that looks like!

Comment: Reading up on `rx` makes this comprehensible and opens up a new world.

Comment: I'll hand you the +1 and answer nominations, for being devoted for this long to answering and a great result.

Comment: @ChrisBarrett Btw, Chris, is there any way I could contact you with some questions about Evil?

Comment: Feel free to message me on Twitter, or post questions on SO where suitable. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
(defmacro fcond (&rest body)
  (labels ((%substitute-last-or-fail 
            (new old seq)
            (loop for elt on seq
                  nconc
                  (if (eql (car elt) old)
                      (when (cdr elt)
                        (error "`%S' must be the last experssion in the clause" 
                               (car elt)))
                    (list new)
                    (list (car elt))))))
    (loop with matched = (gensym)
          with catcher = (gensym)
          for (head . rest) in body
          collect
          `(when (or ,head ,matched)
             (setq ,matched t)
             ,@(%substitute-last-or-fail `(throw ',catcher nil) 'return rest))
          into clauses
          finally
          (return `(let (,matched) (catch ',catcher ,@clauses))))))

(macroexpand '(fcond
               ((= 1 2) (message "1 = 2"))
               ((= 1 1) (message "1 = 1"))
               ((= 1 3) (message "1 = 3") return)
               ((= 1 4) (message "1 = 4"))))
(let (G36434)
  (catch (quote G36435)
    (when (or (= 1 2) G36434)
      (setq G36434 t)
      (message "1 = 2"))
    (when (or (= 1 1) G36434)
      (setq G36434 t)
      (message "1 = 1"))
    (when (or (= 1 3) G36434)
      (setq G36434 t)
      (message "1 = 3")
      (throw (quote G36435) nil))
    (when (or (= 1 4) G36434)
      (setq G36434 t)
      (message "1 = 4"))))
```

Here's something quick to do, what I think you may be after, i.e. something that would mimic the behaviour `switch` in C.

The idea is that all clauses are tested sequentially for equality, and if one matches, then all following clauses are executed, until the `return` keyword (it would be `break` in C, but Lisp uses `return` for the similar purpose in the loop, so I thought that `return` would be better). The code above thus will print:

```
1 = 1
1 = 3
```

Technically, this is not how `switch` works in C, but it will produce the same effect.

One thing I did here for simplicity, which you want to avoid / solve differently - the use of `return` keyword, you probably want to impose stricter rules on how it should be searched for.

Answer (score 3):

## cond

Cond evaluates a series of conditions in a list, each item in a list can be a condition, and then executable instructions.

The example in the Emacs Lisp manual is adequate to demonstrate how it works, I've annotated it here to help you understand how it works.

```
  (cond ((numberp x) x) ;; is x a number? return x
        ((stringp x) x) ;; is x a string? return x
        ((bufferp x) ;; is x a buffer? 
         (setq temporary-hack x) ;; set temporary-hack to buffer x
         (buffer-name x))        ;; return the buffer-name for buffer x
        ((symbolp x) (symbol-value x))) ;; is x a symbol? return the value of x
```

Each part of the condition can be evaluated any way you like, the fact `x` above is in each condition is coincidental.

For example:

```
 (cond ((eq 1 2) "Omg equality borked!") ;; Will never be true
       (t "default")) ;; always true
```

So comparisons with switch are a bit limited, it's essentially a list of if statements, that executes/returns the first true condition's body list.

Hopefully this helps you understand **cond** a bit better.

```
 (cond (condition body ... ) ;; execute body of 1st passing  
       (condition body ... ) ;; condition and return result  
       (condition body ... ) ;; of the final evaluation.
       ;; etc
 )
```

## OR

You can do things similar to switch with OR, depending on how you structure the code.

This isn't functional style, because it relies on side-effects to do what you want, then returns a boolean value for flow control, here's an example in pseudo lisp.

## (or)

```
(or
     (lambda() (do something)
            (evaluate t or nil) ; nil to continue; t to quit.
     )
     (lambda() (do something)
            (evaluate t or nil) ; nil to continue; t to quit.
     )
     (lambda() (do something)
            (evaluate t or nil) ; nil to continue; t to quit.
     )
     (lambda() (do something)
            (evaluate t or nil) ; nil to continue; t to quit.
     )
)
```

Here's working example of a switch like structure using `or`

```
(or
 (when (= 1 1) 
   (progn 
   (insert "hello\n")
           nil))
 (when (= 1 2)  ;; condition fails.
   (progn 
   (insert "hello\n")
           nil)) ;; returns false (nil)
 (when (= 1 1) 
   (progn 
   (insert "hello\n")
           t)) ;; returns true, so we bail.
 (when (= 1 1) 
   (progn 
   (insert "hello\n")
           nil))
)
```

Inserts :

```
hello
hello
```

## (and)

The and operator (not just in Lisp) is also very useful, instead of evaluating everything until true, it evaluates conditions that are true, until a false is evaluated.

Both or & and can be used to build useful logic trees.

Comment: I understand cond now, but I was hoping there is a way to have `else` cases in between. At most I can take it that you show that what I hoped for is not possible within `cond`. Which leaves me with the following: what then?

Comment: This is how cond works, there's nothing to stop you reorganising your logic tree to utilise it. But it's not an if / else.

Comment: +1 for spending the time to teach me. It is really appreciated!

Comment: @Dualinity no worries, it's good to know how to work with raw logic operators, to do fun stuff.

Comment: added a macroless equivalent of @xvxvw's solution.

Comment: Edited my answer to use your or. Very interesting how that works. The idea to just return nil at the end of an `if`.

Comment: Lisp is interesting like this @Dualinity because the syntax is sparse, all functions hold the same level of priority. Constructs like if, for, while are merely functions, so their halo disappears somewhat, and you can operate in very interesting ways, Boolean tricks are quite common among programmers but they usually look a lot more hacky, because of the hierarchy of operators, keywords, structures, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it now according to Chris' idea that breaking it down into seperate functions would make it easier.

EDIT: Now also applied the `or` knowledge gained in this thread gained from Slomojo (no more variables!)

```
(defun sc-uncomment ()
  (interactive)
  (or 
   (if (region-active-p) 
     (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (back-to-indentation)
    nil)
   (if (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) comment-start)
     (sc-check-start)
    (sc-end))))

(defun sc-check-start ()
  (interactive)
  (while (string= (byte-to-string (following-char)) comment-start) 
    (delete-char 1)) 
)

(defun sc-end ()
  (interactive)
  (search-forward comment-start nil t)
  (backward-char 1)
  (kill-line))
)
```